# select tag: first option selected by default

Tags: jquery, html, select

I'm stuck with that issue for almost one day...

Simple select list that looks like this:

```
        <select id="slide_number">
            <option value="slide_1">Slide 1</option>
            <option value="slide_2">Slide 2</option>
            <option value="slide_3">Slide 3</option>
            <option value="slide_4">Slide 4</option>
        </select>
```

And I use this code, to remove the selected attribute, and add it again to the right option.

```
    $('#slide_number').change( function() {
        $('#slide_number option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        $('#slide_number :selected').each( function() { alert( $(this).find('#slide_number :selected') ) } );
        $("#slide_number option[value='slide_" + _t._current_slide + "']" ).attr( 'selected','' );
    } );
```

Everything would be perfect, but after slide 2 it doesn't work properly, it autoselects the first option, even that in chrome i see that the code is changing and the selected tag is being added correctly to other options.

On iPad in Safari I saw that when I choose option 3, it signs option 1 and option 3 at the same time and this is what I think is causing the issue, but I can't get rid of that autoselect of the 1 option :/

I added this alert and it shows that even after removing the selected attribute, option 1 is still selected :(

Thanks for your time and ideas...

Comment: Please explain the logic of using this code `$("#slide_number option[value='slide_" + _t._current_slide + "']" ).attr( 'selected','' );`.

Comment: and what you want to get/do inside the `change` event?

Comment: This is selecting the right slide from the list by value. When I turn right, I change the _current_slide number and I trigger $('#slide_number).trigger('change') so it updates the list.

Change event is simply changing the selected attribute in the list to the current one.

What I saw is when I add multiple='multiple' to the select tag, everything works well, just the select itself is changing to a list that I don't want

Comment: So, on change you want to set the `_t._current_slide` as selected? Btw, which version of jQuery file are you using?

Comment: it's already setted, I want to find that slide in option list and add attr selected. But I want all the others not to be, and the first slide is getting selected somehow and it's not being shown in the code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using the jQuery v1.9.1+

```
$('#slide_number').change(function () {
    $("option[value='slide_" + _t._current_slide + "']", this).prop('selected', true);
    $(':selected', this).each(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: **Before jQuery 1.6**, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.